# With ADO, how do I call an Oracle PL/SQL block and specify input/output bind variables (parameters?)

Tags: oracle, vba, ado

I am trying to call a PL/SQL block with ADO and VBA, but I can't pass input and/or output bind variables (probably aka parameters).

```
dim cn as ADODB.connection
' ... open connection ...

dim plsql as string

plsql =         "declare"
plsql = plsql & "  num_in  number := ?;"
plsql = plsql & "  num_out number; "
plsql = plsql & "begin"
plsql = plsql & "  num_out := num_in * 5;"
plsql = plsql & "  ? := num_out;"
plsql = plsql & "end;"

dim cm as ADODB.command
set cm = new ADODB.command
set cm.activeConnection = cn
cm.commandText = plsql
cm.commandType = adCmdText

cm.parameters.append cm.createParameter(, adDouble, adParamInput,, 5)
cm.parameters.append cm.createParameter(, adDouble, adParamOutput   )

cm.execute  ' FAILS HERE

msgBox(cm.parameters(2))
```

The snippet above fails at the `cm.execute` line with an **ORA-01008: not all variables bound**

I'd appreciate any help towards a solution for my problem.

Comment: I' not sure Oracle allows you to define variables inside the anonymous PL/SQL block like that. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is obviously a trimmed down version of what I actually want to achieve. The real thing is to instantiate a PL/SQL object type, to pass the instance to a procedure, and then to evaluate a few methods and memeber on the object type afterwards.

Comment: Very good question...the infinitely weird ways in which oracle and ado get in conflict are infinitely many...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems as though the statement cannot start with a `declare`. (Thanks to Thomas Jones-Low for his valuable comment).

So, the statement must be enclosed in another `begin .. end` block:

```
' additional begin so that the statement does not start with a declare:
plsql =         "begin "

plsql = plsql & "declare"
plsql = plsql & "  num_in  number := ?;"
plsql = plsql & "  num_out number; "
plsql = plsql & "begin"
plsql = plsql & "  num_out := num_in * 5;"
plsql = plsql & "  ? := num_out;"
plsql = plsql & "end;"

' closing the additional begin:
plsql = plsql & "end;"
```

Now, it works as expected.

Comment: geez, you saved my day! Good Job! thank you! Totally stupid behaviour. How did you come to this solution?